# How can I handle the UniswapV2: LOCKED revert reason when calling swapETHForExactTokens on the Uniswap router2 contract

Tags: web3js, truffle, ganache, uniswap

I have forked the eth mainnet onto my local machine using ganache cli and am trying to call the UNISWAP router2's SwapETHForExactTokens to swap eth for MEME tokens. I call the function from truffle console like so,

```
await uniRouter.methods.swapETHForExactTokens('500', address, sender, '1600952122').send({from: sender, value: web3.utils.toWei('2', 'Ether')}),
```

Where address = [WETH address, MEME token address],
sender = unlocked account,
and uniRouter is an abstraction of the router contract.
When I first start the cli and call the function I get 'runtime error: revert' and on any subsequent calls with varying parameters I also get 'revert reason: UniswapV2: LOCKED'. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Same here but using hardhat-network. Also seen this mentioned as problem on testnets in general. Any ideas / solutions to avoid this?